# FileReference vs File?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, filereference

I want to make a Flash app in which the user can load and save files from and to their local hard drive. While I've often done this in AIR apps using the `File` and `FileStream` classes, I haven't done so before in an SWF.

From what I know the `FileReference` class is used for this, although it seems to have some restrictions due to security risks. I'd like to know what the main differences are between using the `FileReference` class and using the `File` and `FileStream` classes to load and save files.

Comment: filestream: only AIR,  File: FlahPlayer10+, FileReference works always. In oder to load data from local file system use FP10+ and File class, then use the data property. Note: Use file.browse() and before listen for the Complete event on rhe File instance. In the complete handler you can read the data property. See more documentation here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#methodSummary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `File` class extends the `FileReference`.
`FileReference` is safe to be used in the FlashPlayer (in the browser) because it won't let you modify the files in the user machine.

If you want to open a file, you need to as for the user to open it for you with: `FileReference.browse()`.
To save a file, you need to ask the user to save it: `FileReference.save()`

With `File` class you can open, modify and save files without those dialogs.
Furthermore, the `File` class gives you a bunch of useful properties like: `File.desktopDirectory`, `File.documentsDirectory` and such.
You can check if a file exists with the `exists` property and have a much restriction when manipulating file in the user file system.

You can read more about the [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) and [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) classes in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, the differences actually seem much less than I thought so I'm not sure why I asked this. Still, you pretty much answered the question, so thanks.