# Autosaving to xml using fileReference.Save without having a Save As dialog come up

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am trying to save data gathered from within my app to it's accompanying external xml file called `data.xml`. I am using the `fileReference.save` method but it just doesn't seem to be doing the job:

```
function parseXML(xmlData:XML):void
{
    trace("Parsing:");
    trace("-----------------");
    var itemIndex:uint = event.currentTarget.index;
    delete data.item[itemIndex];
    fileReference.save(data, "data.xml");
    trace(xmlData);
}
```

Unfortunately, this causes a 'Save As' dialog box to pop up asking the user where they would like to save the xml file (when what I really want to happen is for the data.xml file in the project's directory to be overwritten automatically without any say on the part of the user).

I have heard that `FileStream` is the way to go (especially being I am going to deploy this on Air for iOS), but I don't know how to implement it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I have updated my question with the suggestion below, but it still doesn't work. The `data.xml` file is in the same directory called 'RecipeMatcher2' on my Desktop i.e. /Desktop/RecipeMatcher2/ (I am using Mac OS X), but I also want it to resolve to whatever path the file will be stored in when on the iPhone.

```
function parseXML(xmlData:XML):void
{
    trace("Parsing:");
    trace("-----------------");
    var itemIndex:uint = event.currentTarget.index;
    file = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
    file = file.resolvePath("data.xml");
    delete data.item[itemIndex];
    var writeStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    writeStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    writeStream.writeUTFBytes(data.toXMLString());
    writeStream.close();
    trace('xml file saved');
}
```

I originally load my xml data like so:

```
loader = new URLLoader();
// listens to see if data has fully loaded//
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataLoaded);
//loads local xml file with URLrequest method//
loader.load(new URLRequest("data.xml"));
```

and here are my public vars relevant to this question:

```
public var loader:URLLoader;
public var file:File;
public var data:XML;
public var items:XMLList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileReference` class is safe for web browsers because it doesn't let you mess with users files without his consent.

But, as you are using AIR you can use the `File` class that extends the `FileReference`.
Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122172/filereference-vs-file/16123731#16123731) to understand the difference between them.

Here's how you can use the `FileStream` class:

```
var file:File = new File().resolvePath("myFile.txt");

var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeUTF("Hello world!");
stream.close();
```

And you can read more about the [FileStream class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) here.

---

**EDIT**: Looking at your current edited question I'd recommend you to load the xml data with a `File`/`FileReference`, something like the following:

```
private var file:File = new File();

private function loadFile():void 
{
    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileComplete);
    file.resolvePath("data.xml"); // Or whatever your file is located
    file.load();
}

private function saveFile():void 
{
    var writeStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    /*
     * FileMode.WRITE will truncate (empty) the file on open.
     * FileMode.APPEND will open the file "as is" and write in the end of it.
     */
    writeStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    writeStream.writeBytes(data); // Any other write method can be used
    writeStream.close();
}

private function onFileComplete(event:Event):void 
{
    var xml:XML = XML(file.data); // Your XML is here!
    parseXML(xml); // Do your stuff here
}
```

As you can see, once we get a reference to the file in the file system we can read/write data from/to it freely.

Comment: And how would I adopt this to saving an `XML` object to file like in my example above? (XML object is called `data`)